# How to calculate the percentage of records when comparing hive tables?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

Two Hive tables called table1 and table2 are there. I got the count of both of these tables. I created a third table called abc with the non matching records from table1 and table2. How can I get the percentage of number of records in table abc compare to the entire count of table1 and table2?

```
1. select count(*) from table1 A

2. select count(*) from table2 B
3. create table dbo.abc as 
   select A.column1, A.columnb from table A
   inner join table B
   where A.column3 <> B.column3

4. how to get the percentage of records in table abc? 
    for example:   count(*) from abc 
                   -------------------- *100
                   count(*) from A + B
```

Expected output is:

```
Example: 
  number_of_non_matching_records = 20%
```

Comment: What is the "entire count of table1 and table2"?  Are you trying to do this without generating an additional table?

Comment: the total count of table1 and table2 is 514789 records. but the count can change every time because the table gets updated. will it be easier if can generate an additional table?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this in one statement?

```
select count(*) as combos_in_ab,
       sum(case when a.column3 <> b.column3 then 1 else 0 end) as combos_in_3,
       avg(case when a.column3 <> b.column3 then 1.0 else 0 end) as percent_in_3
from a cross join
     b;
```